# Calculate number zeros of poliniomyal complex function (Argument Principle)

Tags: complex-analysis

I have to calculate de number of zeros of the polinomyal function $P(z)=z^4+2z^2-z+1$ in the I Quadrant.

My attempt:

I have tried two ways: one with the Rouché Theorem, but I didn't know how to compare this polinomyal with other in this domain. The other one, I have tried with the Argument principle, defininig a path like the first quarter of a circle with radius $R$, and taking the limit when $R\to\infty$. But I have troubles calculating this integral.

Edit:
In the second way I have alredy proved that the polinomyal doesn't have zeros in both axis, in order to prove the restone with the argument principle. But, my problem is, in fact, in this part of the proof.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1106169/42969 for a similar question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a partial answer, but I will give advice at the end on how you can finish it.

Note that $P(z)$ is not in $(-\infty,0]$ if $z$ is on either the real or the imaginary axis (prove this if you haven’t yet). Take the path, $\gamma_R$, that goes from $iR$ to $0$ to $R$ along each axis followed by the quarter-circle path from $R$ back to $i R$. We can choose this $R > 0$ such that all the roots of $P$ are contained in the open disk of radius $R$. It follows then that $P$ is nonzero along this path.

We want to use the argument principle, so we need to consider the integral, $(2\pi i)^{-1}\int_{\gamma_R} P’/P$, and take the limit as $R$ approaches infinity.

**Part 1**

The image of $P$ on the polygonal path is not in $(\infty,0]$, so we can use the principal complex logarithm on $\{z\colon \lvert\arg z\rvert<\pi\}$. Then $P’/P = (\log\circ P)’$, and

$$\begin{align*}
\int (\log\circ P)’ &= \log P(R) - \log P(iR) \\
&= \log\big(R^4 + 2R^2 - R + 1\big) - \log\big(R^4 - 2R^2 - iR + 1\big) \\
&= \log\big(R^4 \big(1 + 2R^{-2} - R^{-3} + R^{-4}\big)\big) - \log\big(R^4\big(1 - 2R^{-2} - iR^{-3} + R^{-4}\big)\big) \\
&= \log\big(1 + 2R^{-2} - R^{-3} + R^{-4}\big) - \log\big(1 - 2R^{-2} - iR^{-3} + R^{-4}\big)
\end{align*}$$

on this path.

I’ve used the product-to-sum identity to separate the $R^4$ factors from each term and cancel. Usually it doesn’t hold for a complex logarithm, but the use here is justified because $R > 0$. The last expression approaches $0$ as $R$ goes to infinity, so this integral does not contribute in the limit.

**Part 2**

For the integral along the quarter-circle path, I leave it to you to show this:

- $P’(z)/P(z) = 4z^{-1} + \big({-4}z^2 + 3z - 4\big)\big/\big(z^5 + 2z^3 - z^2 + z\big)$
- The integral of the first term is $2\pi i$ and thus contributes one to the count of roots.
- The $\mathsf{ML}$ inequality implies that the absolute value for the integral of the second term is $\mathcal{O}(1/R)$ so it does not contribute in the limit.

Combined with the previous facts, this tells us that there is exactly one root in the first quadrant. Even better, $P$ has real coefficients so there is exactly one root in each quadrant!

Edit: I’m adding this to motivate the magical $4z^{-1}$ trick. We know that $P’(z)/P(z)$ is asymptotically similar to $4z^{-1}$ as $\lvert z\rvert$ approaches infinity, so it makes sense to separate the integrand into those two terms.

Interestingly enough, even though we cannot—in general—hope for better than $\mathcal{O}(1/R)$ in the preceding argument, we actually have $\mathcal{O}\big(1/R^2\big)$ for this specific case.

Comment: Thanks! I have understand all the prove, you have explained it in a fabolous way. I'm going to work in it tomorrow, I think I can do all the calculus. I'm so gratefull because I think this is a way to prove some similar problems!

Comment: @GoRza I tried to structure the argument so that parts of it could be generalized to other problems that aren’t as special as this one. I’ve added an edit that hopefully motivates the reasoning a bit more.

Comment: sorry, but I don't understand why $\int_{\gamma} 4z^{-1}dz=2\pi i$ with $\gamma$ the first quarter of the circle. I know that $\int_{\partial D(0,R)}z^{-1}dz=2\pi i$, but I don't understand how divded the path in quarters, would divide the integral by 4.

Comment: @GoRza The quarter-circle path can be parameterized as $R e^{i t}$ for $0\leq t\leq \pi/2$. Then the integral along this path is $\int 4 z^{-1} = \int_0^{\pi/2} \big(4 i R e^{i t}\big)\big/\big(R e^{i t}\big) \, dt$.