# Number of zeros of a polynomial (Argument Principle)

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $\alpha\in \mathbb{R}$ and $P(z)=z^4+z^3+4z^2+\alpha z+3$. I have to calculate the number of zeros in $\operatorname{Re}(z)<0$.

**My attempt**

I have tried to calculate with the same process as in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4173139/885493).

I know that if $\alpha\notin[1,3]$, $P(z)\notin (-\infty,0] \ \forall z\in i\mathbb R$. So, in the integral I can put $\frac{P'(z)}{P(z)}=(\log(P(z))'$, and then I can conclude as in the answer.

My problem is when $\alpha\in[1,3]$. I don't know how to do it, can you guide me?

Comment: We are evaluating $P(z)$ at $z=ri$ and letting $r$ go from $-\infty$ to $\infty$. Let's evaluate and separate the real and imaginary parts. We get $P(ri)=(r^4-4r^2+3)+i(-r^3+\alpha r)$. Observe that both real an imagine parts are polynomials that are easy to find the roots. We don't really need the roots, but their relative position. Each time $r$ crosses a root, one of the two polynomials changes sign and therefore $P(ri)$ moves from one quadrant to another. The sequence of jumps between quadrants tells you the number of time that $P(\mathbb{R}i)$ winds around the origin.

Comment: But, then I cannot solve the integral? And in the semicircle?

Comment: The integral is an integer multiple of $2\pi i$ and that integer has the geometric interpretation of being the number of time the image of the path winds around the origin. By finding out that number we are computing the integral.

Comment: Okay, I alredy know that but for no reason I have tried tosolve the integral, thanks. But in the semi-circle of radius R, how do you calculate the number of times that the path winds around the origin? I don't know how to do it geometrically