# Find how many solutions of the equation $z^6+6z+10=0$ are in each quadrant.

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-analysis, polynomials, roots

Find how many solutions of the equation $z^6+6z+10=0$ are in each quadrant.

This polynomial has six solutions by TFTA. I just don't know how to show what they are and where they lie. Any solutions or help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The title is a little "off". A quick sketch reveals there are no real solutions, so all of them are complex. In which quadrant of the real xy plane do complex numbers lie?

Comment: Note that complex solutions to polynomials with real coefficients, $z_0$, ``come" with their complex conjugate $\overline{z_0}$ (as this ensures that the coefficients of the polynomial will end up being real.

Comment: 1Q: 1.37+0.88i; 2Q: -1.17+0.49i, -0.20+1.51i; 3Q: -1.17-0.49i, -0.20-1.51i; 4Q: 1.37-0.88i.

Comment: Showing at least one in each quadrant is easy - easy to show no real roots or pure imaginary, and the sum of roots being zero gives real parts have to be of both signs, and obviously the conjugates imply all quadrants have roots. Fixing how many roots are there in any one quadrant should fix everything else.

Comment: Check http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/809402/zeros-of-a-polynomial?rq=1