# Finding roots of an equation dealing complex numbers

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, contest-math

For the equation
$z^6
 + 6z + 20 = 0,$ z is a complex number

Putting z=x+iy is tiresome . Moreover my question demands to find the roots lying in each quadrant . Is there an easy way out?

Edit.

> The actual statement is
> The number of roots in 1st,2nd,3rd ,4th quadrant are

Comment: Compute the Galois group

Comment: @SenZen I am not aware about it could you brief it

Comment: There are no real roots, so complex conjugate pairs

Comment: As this is an exercise of complex analysis and you are mentioning quadrants, I doubt that you really need to find the solutions of this equation. Can you state the question precisely?

Comment: Are you sure that 6 shouldn't be a 5?

Comment: Write out the *exact* question, word for word please.

Comment: @SenZen the qo. Is as it and actually wants how many roots in each quadrant

Comment: How many roots in each quadrant is a completely different question to finding them!!!

Comment: @Anusha Then write this in the question. Finding the number of roots in each quadrant is completely different from finding the exact solutions. I smell some Rouché shenanigans here.

Comment: @SenZen can it be done without actually knowing the roots?

Comment: Put in $x+iy$, equate real and imaginary parts to get 2 polynomials with real solutions, then use continuity of polynomials and IVT to prove existence of solutions within intervals.

Comment: Not the same constant term, but maybe it doesn't matter, check this https://math.stackexchange.com/q/809402/399263

Comment: @Klaus done it,

Comment: @SenZen could you give me a quick rundown of how you'd calculate the Galois group and through that the roots of this equation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set $z=a+ib\;$ and expand
$$(a+ib)^6 + 6(a+ib) + 20 = 0 \tag{1}$$
Equating real and imaginary parts to $0$ we obtain the system
$$\begin{aligned}a^6-15a^4b^2+15a^2b^4-b^6+6a+20&=0 \quad\quad\quad\quad (*)\\
6a^5b-20a^3b^3+6ab^5+6b&=0 \quad\quad\quad\quad (**)\end{aligned}$$
Recall that the system has six solutions $(a,b)\in \mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}.$ Clearly $ab\neq0.$

Take the equation $(**)$ and divide it by $2b.$ We obtain $$3a^5-10a^3b^2+3ab^4+3=0 \tag{2}$$ Let us consider $(2)$ as equation in variable $a.$
Descartes rule of signs says that $(2)$ has $2$ positive and $3$ negative roots $a$ (more precisely, two $a$'s have positive real part and three have negative real part, but we know that all $a$'s are real).

Recall that all solutions of $(1)$ are in pairs  $(a_1,\pm b_1), (a_2,\pm b_2),(a_3, \pm b_3).$
Only one of $a$'s is missing in $(**)$, thus we can conclude that $(**)$ has one positive double root, one negative double root and one simple root $a.$

> Therefore, one solution of the original equation $(1)$ lies in the first quadrant, two in the second, two in the third and one in the fourth.

To verify our result, let us apply Descartes rule to $(*):$

1. if $\;20-b^6<0$ then $(*)$ has $3$ positive and $3$ negative roots $a_i,$ which is impossible
2. if $\;20-b^6=0$ then $(*)$ has $2$ positive and $3$ negative roots $a_i$
3. if $\;20-b^6>0$ then $(*)$ has $2$ positive and $4$ negative roots $a_i$

Our conclusion is justified. As a by-result, necessarilly $\;20-b^6\geq 0.$

Comment: Umm I have 1 doubt if equation is a variable in a as in eq 2 it must have 5 roots when I'm applying descartes rule I get 2 +be and 3-ve roots what do you say?

Comment: You´re right. I started with the first equation, switched to the second  ... and wrote my solution wrongly. I am going to fix it. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for correcting